# Compute the integral $\displaystyle\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth plane domain of unit area. Let $u(x,y) = 3x^2+y^2$. If $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ denotes the outer normal derivative on $\partial \Omega$, the boundary of $\Omega$. Compute:

$$\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula
$$\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=\iint_\Omega \Delta u.$$

Comment: what is the unit normal on omega

Comment: ???? Using the formula you don't need the outer normal derivetive, but the laplacian of $u$.

Comment: Where did the differential go? $\Delta u$ is for [discrete calculus](https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/DCalc.pdf). Right?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash, $\Delta$ is the Laplacian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator.